# Set NavigationControll back to viewcontroller 0 from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm receiving a Push Notification from AppDelegate and I'm currently able to push the view Where I want, But when I try to do this a second time it shows me this error.

```
 2014-07-14 08:20:08.055 mobile-app[11607:60b] Warning: Attempt to present 
<UINavigationController: 0x15e5a620> on <OptionsTabBarViewController: 0x15e7b340> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I assume this is because the NavigationController viewController is still on the Navigation set on the View I set it up after it pushed the view.

My code is the following:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

        [tabBarController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"push_display_incomming_call" sender:self];
        _callID = [userInfo objectForKey:@"call_id"];
```

Comment: Can you please explain your problem little more . After receiving push what you are trying to do?

Comment: @vntstudy after i receive the push i show a viewcontroller with a button if user taps on it it pushes it to another viewcontroller.

Comment: Before pushing the viewcontroller , check for current view controller value in logs that might be coming as NULL.

Comment: But how that solves wether i'm able to push the view again?

Comment: If it is coming NULL , that means you are losing your object somewhere , then you have to store it somewhere. First check for NULL .

Comment: The _callID is defined on the AppDelegate I just call this on the view from there.